# Grouping items inside a Scroll View using Xcode 4.3.2 and storyboards

Tags: ios, xcode, scrollview

I have a large image in a Image View, inside a Scroll View, in the View.

```
View Controller
    View
        Scroll View
            Image View - 1750x3000image
            Button - button1
            Button - button2
            Button - button3
            Button - button4
```

When I zoom in and out, the button doesn't track with the larger image.  Scrolling around, the button does track along with the image.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have areas of the larger image be buttons, or have buttons hovering over those areas.

Comment: could you be more clear? what do you mean by does/doesn't track?

Comment: image it's a pin on a map.  Zoomed out the pin is on NY.  When I zoom in, the pin moves away from NY and ends up in N/W Canada.  The image zooms in relation to the fingers position, the button zooms in and out in relation to the top left 0,0

Comment: so the Buttons should be the way the pins work in the maps app, where a pin sticks to the geolocation, and adjacent pins move closer when zooming out?

Comment: yes, a pin is stuck in the ground.  When the ground moves, the pin moves with it...

Comment: Did you try adding the buttons as subview of the imageview, instead of adding it directly to the ScrollView?

Comment: I did in the Interface Builder but they don't scale with the imageView. But, when I added them in the code and did a [imageView addSubview:button1]; it did. So now I have it working by adding the buttons in the Controller.m file and not IB

Answer (score 0):

Based on what i can guess, you want your image to be like a button. Just add a UIButton custom type (frame same as the image view) with clear color background to your scrollview on top of the image view.

edit: Try adding the buttons as subview of the imageview, instead of adding it directly to the ScrollView?

Comment: sorry, I updated the question to show that I'll be adding lots of buttons on top of the 1 image.

Comment: when you add it in the IB, are you sure you are adding it as a subview to the imageView? and not to the scroll view? Make sure to drag the button onto the imageview in the IB document outline. Basically, your buttons should be indented a level more than the imageView, which is indented a level more than the parent view. not sure why IB would behave any different. It'd help if you can share a screenshot of the IB document outline